# How to fix that to not display h1 and p tags all in first section

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following code.

There have 6 section with some `h1` and under `p` tags used `positon: fixed;` this need to be centered horizontal and vertical the `h1` and `p` tags.

The problem is in some older browser this `section` and `h1`, `p` tags show in same page so the first section display all six `h1` and `p` tags. Is there some possibility that in one `section`, page only display that one `h1` and `p` tag?

```css
h1 {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3em;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  user-select: none;
  position: fixed;
}
p {
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<section class="test1" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>test1</h1>
      <li>
        <p>test</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="test2" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>test2</h1>
      <li>
        <p>testtest</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="test3" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>test3</h1>
      <li>
        <p>testtesttest</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="test4" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>test4</h1>
      <li>
        <p>testtesttesttest</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="test5" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>test5</h1>
      <li>
        <p>testtesttesttesttest</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="test6" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>test6</h1>
      <li>
        <p>testtesttesttesttesttest</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

test1-6 and p tags in same page first:

[IE Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqHf1.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting here. You're setting a specific fixed position for your `h1` and then putting 6 `h1` on the page, of course they are going to overlap. Can you post an image of your *desired* layout?

Comment: also confused about those h1 and p inside ul li ??

Comment: Do you have any idea what position:fixed does? I dont want to be rude but  please first understand the syntax and the code that you are using and second please always share your main goal as to what you want it to look like or work as so that you can better explain what is wrong.

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/tswjtpc6/ ] Maybe you're looking something.

Comment: Thanks for ideas. My first thing is want to do: with fixed position display h1 and p tags not in same first all in section tag. That is possible? somehow with z-index? Or if me set fixed position there is no way? TY